# MVC Application Not Working in chrome and edge working fine in firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, iis, microsoft-edge

My MVC 4 project working fine in firefox when hosted in live server (windows server 2012) but not working in chrome and edge, but working fine in debug mode, it is also working fine when hosted in local iis. When running the application in the following difference where found local iis and live (windows server 2012).

**The image local iis** [image]

**The image server iis**

[image]

Comment: What is "not working"? you need to use the developer console and network tools (e.g. in Chrome) to get some kind of Error Message etc. These Screenshots are not very helpful

Comment: login functionally is not working after login it the application will redirect to  dashboard page in firefox it is working fine but in chrome it shows login page it self.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer buddy ? I have the same issue now